# Automatic login to gmail

Tags: java, google-api, parameter-passing

I want to login to the Gmail account automatically without asking for username & password, which I will provide using a URL(Gmail), i.e when I run my java application, it should display the "inbox" page of the Gmail (The login page of the Gmail should not be displayed) and should open first unread mail.

How can we pass the "username" & "password" to achieve the above scenario?

I want to achieve this 'only' using java.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
Every web browser can be set to remember your login name and password, but this cannot be in the URL. It would not be safe.

Comment: + 1 for *"It would not be safe"*